# Ambiguous use go 'subscript'

Tags: json, swift, xcode, subscript

I am trying to get data that has been encoded as json in a php script.

My code:

```
func getJson(completion: @escaping (Array<CarPark>) -> Void) {

        activityIndicatior.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicatior.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicatior.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicatior)
        self.activityIndicatior.startAnimating()

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {

                    do{

                        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                        for index in 0..<myJson.count {

                            if let entry = myJson[index] as? NSDictionary{
                            let name = entry["Name"] as! String
                           let longitude = Double(entry["Longitude"] as! String)
                           let latitude = Double(entry["Latitude"] as! String)

                          let quiet = Int(entry["Quiet"] as! String)
                        let moderate = Int(entry["Moderate"] as! String)

                            let busy = Int(entry["Busy"] as! String)
                            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                            print("coordinate lat is : \(coordinate.latitude)")
                            print("coordinate long is : \(coordinate.longitude)")
                            print("coordinate full is: \(coordinate)")
                            let tempPark = CarPark(name: name, latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!, quiet: quiet!, moderate: moderate!, busy: busy!, coordinate: coordinate, level: "Nil")
                            let level = tempPark.calcAvailability()
                            tempPark.level = level
                            print("Availability is \(tempPark.level)")
                            self.tempCarParks.append(tempPark)
                           // print("amount of parks: \(self.carParks.count)")
                           print("name of parks in array: \(self.tempCarParks[index].name)")
                            print("Availability is \(tempPark.level)")
                            }

                        }
                       completion(self.tempCarParks)

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        print("Error")
                    }
                }
            }
    }

        task.resume()

    }
```

I am getting an error that says 'Ambiguous use of subscript' at the line:

if let entry = myJson[index] as? NSDictionary{

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know `myJson` is an array why do you cast the object to unspecified `AnyObject`?

That causes the error, the compiler needs to know the concrete types of all subscripted objects. Help the compiler then the compiler helps you:

```
  let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [[String:Any]]

  for entry in myJson { // don't use old-fashioned index based loops

     let name = entry["Name"] as! String
 ...
```

`.mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift.